# How to display data inline?

Tags: java, html, css, spring, jsp

I hava a `play.jsp`  and I wanted to display the data in a formatted way like the question id and question in a single line and answer in next single line. How can I do that? I would be very thankful for the answers.

```
<div class="container">
   <table class="table">
   <center>  
  <p>Question</p>
   <c:forEach items="${quiz}" var="qz">
  <p> ${qz.id}</p>
  <p>${qz.question}</p>
  <p>${qz.ans1}</p>
  <p> ${qz.ans2} </p>
 <p>${qz.ans3} </p>
</c:forEach>

</center>
</table>
</div>
```

Now I am getting output in this way
[image: Now I am getting output in this way]

Comment: Well, your html table is way off. You should probably be using `div`(s), but since it isn't clear how you want the page to render - you should edit your question.

Comment: @Bishwa Karki Welcome to stackOverflow , If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put them in the same `<p></p>` like `<p>${qz.id} ${qz.question}</p>`

Also `<center>` tag was deprecated in HTML5 because it defines the presentation of its contents -- it doesn't describe its contents.

Use CSS instead:

```
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <div class="centered">
      <p>Question</p>
      <c:forEach items="${quiz}" var="qz">
        <p>${qz.id} ${qz.question}</p>
        <p>${qz.ans1}</p>
        <p> ${qz.ans2} </p>
        <p>${qz.ans3} </p>
      </c:forEach>
    </div>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what OP posted (only indented).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, really? `<p> ${qz.id}</p><p>${qz.question}</p>` and `<p>${qz.id} ${qz.question}</p>` are not the same

Comment: @BishwaKarki, one more thing, the `center` tag is no longer supported in HTML5, so use CSS to center stuff, check my updated answer.

Comment: @DanielH I *qualified* it with ***appears***. I'm glad it worked for OP, but I really wish the desired format was there (whatever that may be). And, I probably would have preferred something using `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. Such is life.

Comment: @DanielH thank you alot 
I wanted to ask you one more question, suppose the correct answer is any one of the option and I wanted to increase the number if the user gives the correct answer, and I think this will be nice if done using javascript. And my question is how can this be done using angujar js?

Comment: @BishwaKarki I don't have much knowledge about angular js, could not help you with that